# Independence of $\min(X,Y)$ and $\max(X,Y)$ for independent $X$, $Y$?

Tags: probability, random-variable, independence

What's the reasoning for checking the independence of

$$\min(X,Y)$$ and $$\max(X,Y)$$ for independent r.v.s $X,Y$?

Is it possible that $\min$ and $\max$ both select the same r.v. in which case they would be dependent? No, because that would mean that $X=Y$, i.e. $X$ and $Y$ would not be independent.

Does the independence regarding functions of independent r.v.s apply here? Yes? In that case $X,Y$ independent $\implies$ $\min(X,Y),\space \max(X,Y)$ independent.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to say two random variables are dependent "when such and such happens."  They're either independent or not, no matter what values they happen to take on.  I'll also point out that $X = Y$ does not imply they're dependent because they could both equal the same constant with probability one.

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting this. Independence is both incredibly important and counter-intuitive. +1

Comment: +1  upvoting on the ground that questions leading to interesting answers must have some merit!

Comment: @dsaxton I've thought that a r.v. is always dependent with itself?

Comment: @mavavilj A deterministic r.v., i.e. an r.v. which equals a constant with probability one, is independent of itself.  You can check that from the definition of independence.  You appear to be relying on a layman's definition of dependence (non-independence) which does not properly address this case.

Comment: Define image(X)  (I would think it means the image of the function from the outcome space, i.e., the set of values the random variable may take, but then why would $1$ be special compared to any other number?)

Answer (score 11):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent *continuous* random variables, then $\max(X,Y)$ and
$\min(X,Y)$ are independent random variables if and only if one of the
following two conditions holds:

- $P(X > Y) = 1$
- $P(X < Y) = 1$

Note that the above conditions mean that $P(X=Y) = 0$ but this does
not mean that $(X=Y)$ is the same as the *impossible* event, that is,
there is *no* outcome $\omega$ in the sample space for which
$X(\omega) = Y(\omega)$. Those thoroughly confused by this notion
should recall that they might have been told that
for a *continuous* random variable $V$,
$P(V = a) = 0$ for *all* real numbers $a$ even though it is manifestly
true that $V$ *can* take on value $a$ for some particular $a$, 
and if they have
swallowed that whopper, then accepting that $P(X=Y)=0$ does not
mean that the event $(X=Y)$ will never occur is just a small
additional stretch of their credulity.

When $X$ and $Y$ are independent *discrete* random variables, then
the above condition needs to be relaxed slightly, and it is possible
to have $P(X=Y) > 0$. For example, if $(X,Y)$ takes on values
$(1,0), (2,0), (1,1), (2,1)$ with equal probability $\frac 14$, then
$(\min(X,Y), \max(X,Y))$ takes on values $(0,1), (0,2), (1,1), (1,2)$
with equal probability $\frac 14$ and thus $\min(X,Y)$ and 
$\max(X,Y))$ are
independent. A little thought will show that $(\min(X,Y), \max(X,Y))$
is the same as $(Y,X)$ in this case. A little further thought will
show that if $P(X=Y)>0$, then it must be that there is a *unique*
$a$ such that $P(X=a, Y= a) >0$ and that for all *other* real numbers
$b$, $P(X=b, Y= b) =0$. For independent discrete random variables
$X$ and $Y$, the probability mass function has nonzero values at
all points on a rectangular grid, and this grid must be strictly
below or strictly above the line $x=y$ or must have only one point
(the upper left corner or the lower right corner) on the line $x=y$; 
the point $(1,1)$ in the example above.

---

An interesting follow-up question is:

When  $X$ and $Y$ are *dependent* random variables, is it *possible* for
$\max(X,Y)$ and $\min(X,Y)$ to be independent random variables?

to which the answer is *Yes, it is possible.*  Consider the case when
$X$ and $Y$ are jointly continuous random variables uniformly
distributed on the set

$$\left\{(x,y)\colon \frac 12 \leq x \leq 1,
 0 \leq y \leq x-\frac 12\right\}
\bigcup 
\left\{(x,y)\colon 0 \leq x \leq \frac 12,
 \frac 12 \leq y < x + \frac 12\right\}$$
The joint density of the minimum and maximum can be worked out
as described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/50391/6633)
where it is shown that if $Z = \min(X,Y)$ and $W = \max(X,Y)$,
then 
$$f_{Z,W}(z,w) =  \begin{cases}
f_{X,Y}(z,w) + f_{X,Y}(w,z), & \text{if}~w > z,\\
\\
0, & \text{if}~w < z.
\end{cases}
$$
Applying this, it can be shown that the joint density of
$Z$ and $W$ is uniform on interior of the square with vertices
$(0,\frac 12), (\frac 12, \frac 12), (\frac 12, 1),
(0,1)$, and so $Z \sim U[0,\frac 12]$ and $W \sim U[\frac 12,1]$
are independent random variables.

Comment: So do the first two conditions say the same as $X≠Y$?

Comment: @mavavilj What do you mean by $X\neq Y$ when $X$ and $Y$ are random variables?