# min/max and probability distributions

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, random-variable, density-function

We have two identically distributed, independent, uniform variables on interval $[0,1]$ : $X_{1}$, $X_{2}$. And $Y_{1}=\max(X_{1},X_{2})$, $Y_{2}=\min(X_{1},X_{2})$. I want to find distribution $f(y_{1}|y_{2})$ and $f(y_{2}|y_{1})$. So I tried to approach it like this: firstly try to calculate distribution of $f(y_{1},y_{2}=w)$ as a derivative of: $$F_{Y_{1},Y_{2}}(y_{1},y_{2}=w)=\mathbb{P}([{X_{1}}\leq y_{1} \wedge X_{2} \leq y_{1}]\wedge [X_{1} \leq w\ \vee X_{2}\leq w])$$ and I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Hint: the chance that the larger of the $X_i$ does not exceed $y_1$ is the chance that *both* of the $X_i$ do not exceed $y_1$.  The chance that the smaller of the $X_i$ does not exceed $y_2$ is the complement of the chance that *both* of the $X_i$ exceed $y_2$.

Comment: Try to prove that in general, $$f_{\min\{X,Y\}, \max\{X,Y\}}(a,b) = \begin{cases}f_{X,Y}(a,b)+f_{X,Y}(b,a),&b>a,\\0,&b<a\end{cases}$$ which for the case of iid $U(0,1)$ random variables leads to $(\min,\max)$ being uniformly distributed on a triangular region, and shows that the conditional density of one given the other is a uniform density over intervals that I leave you to determine for yourself.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/50391/133995