# What kind of distribution to use for data between a known max and min?

Tags: distributions, excel

This is probably a stupidly simple question, but I am absolutely a layperson when it comes to most of this stuff and I understand just very surface level stuff. Everything I can find online searching this up seems to be extremely complicated instead of just giving me a direct answer.

The gist is I'm trying to use Excel to quickly draw up a distribution of some data. I was originally going to do a bell curve/normal distribution, but the data has a rather high standard deviation and a low mean. In fact, `mean - 2*stdev` is out of bounds of the minimum value,  and `mean + 3*stdev` exceeds the maximum. Which is probably fine-ish since this is probability and stats stuff, right? But for a fact this is data that's never supposed to go negative, and not only is `mean - 2*stdev` below the min, but it's also negative.

For example if I have a mean of 15,200, and a stdev of 8,600, max and min being around 1k/35k or so respectively - what would be an ideal way to go about graphing/visualizing this data in excel? In simple terms?

I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272541/min-max-and-probability-distributions) post as well which points [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50376/determine-density-of-minx-y-and-maxx-y-for-independently-uniform-distr/50391#50391), but these are pretty complicated to me. Not asking anyone to do this for me or anything but if you can identify a  that I can go try to read about or find a tutorial on how to do in excel, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: _Everything I can find online searching this up seems to be extremely complicated instead of just giving me a direct answer_ probably because you are vague... we don't know if it's discrete, what's the pdf shape and nothing else... probably you are lacking on some notion of what's a distribution, for what I can see, it could be exponential, poisson, uniform, or many many other distributions, depending on where the data comes from

Comment: @albertosinigaglia  Fair assessment, I'm definitely lacking on the knowledge side here. I was really just trying to do up a bell curve based on those numbers, but a moderate portion of  the curve is below the y axis and these are numbers that aren't supposed to ever go negative. Is there a specific distribution that consists only of positive numbers  that I could try to run/apply?

Comment: You can graph/visualize data without choosing any distributional model. Whether/ how you might choose a model depends in part what the model is being used for, which is not clear here. Simply knowing bounds on a variable is hardly a good basis to choose models for it. An example of a distributional model that has a hard upper and lower limit (not a limit based on the observed values, but on what values are possible) would be a 4 parameter beta distribution. That is not to imply that this would be suitable for your application, or even that you would necessarily need to choose a distribution.

Comment: For example, you say "I was [...] trying to do a bell curve" (by which I assume you intend to say "trying to fit a normal distribution" ... but the purpose of doing so is unclear. What calculation do you need a normal distribution for that you could not do at least as well without assuming a specific distribution for?

Comment: @glen_b I sorta get what you mean, the data is like loan data, so the idea I had was based on the values (mean, stdev) for a given year, make a more general plot probability vs. loan amount which is why I was stuck on the numbers being  non-negative and not exceeding the maximum approvable. I suppose just drawing the bell curve and extracting the section between my limits might suffice then for something suitable-ish?

Comment: I don't see the relevance of normal distributions to this at all, but it's really not clear to me what you're doing with it. What are you trying to find out? Your post mentions drawing a distribution, but you can draw an empirical distribution function, which should fit all your constraints. What would having a distribution function tell you? I don't follow what you're extracting from this.

Comment: @Glen_b understandable confusion, I'm not really sure either. I'm taking a sort of basic stats class and was trying to just apply some of the stuff from class to the data and see what happens. I don't have a clear purpose other than just learning right now, I was just doing it to see if anything would click once I have the graph drawn up in front of me. I'll look into empirical distribution function and see what that looks like.

Comment: The empirical (cumulative) distribution function (edf or ecdf) as a function of $x$ is just the proportion of the observations that are at or below each possible $x$ value; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function has example pictures (the step function is the edf). The program **R** has the `ecdf` function. It would not be particularly hard to obtain an ecdf in Excel from its definition. Depending on what sort of variable you're measuring, with a skewed distribution on strictly positive values is sometimes taking logs helps.