# Density of min(X,Y), max(X,Y) for iid Uniform (Related to other post)

Tags: independence, joint-distribution, uniform-distribution

I was looking at [Determine density of $\min(X,Y)$ and $\max(X,Y)$ for independently uniform distributed variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50376/determine-density-of-minx-y-and-maxx-y-for-independently-uniform-distr)

There's a very detailed answer, but while I was doing the same exercise by myself I was thinking in a similar but slightly different way, which lead me to a different answer. Here I'll share with you my work so I can understand the why of the difference.

Also, I am making focus on the value of the CDF, and **not yet working on the joint pdf**.

Given $(Z,W)=(min(X,Y), max(X,Y))$ for $X,Y$ iid Uniform(0,1), find the CDF.

I thought of :
\begin{equation} 
P(Z\leq a,W\leq b)=\\
P(min(X,Y)\leq a,max(X,Y)\leq b)=\\
P( \{X\leq a, a \leq Y\leq b\}  \cup \{a \leq X \leq b, Y\leq a\}  )=(1)\\
P(\{X\leq a, a \leq Y\leq b\}) + P(\{a \leq X \leq b, Y\leq a\})= (2)\\
P(X\leq a) P( a \leq Y\leq b) + P(a \leq X \leq b) P(Y\leq a)= (3)\\
F_X(a)( F_Y(b)-F_Y(a)) + ( F_X(b)-F_X(a)) F_Y(a)=\\
F(a)(F(b)-F(a))+ (F(b)-F(a)) F(a)= (4)\\
2F(a)(F(b)-F(a)) =\\
2F(a)F(b) - 2F(a)^2
\end{equation}
Where $a$ would be the minimum, $b$ the maximum and I use:

1. {X is the minimum, Y the maximum} union {Y is the minimum, X the maximum}
2. Probability of the union of disjoint set
3. Independence of $X$ and $Y$
4. The fact that $F_X$ = $F_Y$ = $F$

This result is different to $F_{X,Y}(a,b) + F_{X,Y}(b,a) - F_{X,Y}(a,a)$, as given in the original question (there are differences in variable naming, but the setting is essentially the same)

I notice that if I use the idea (4) about equality of CDFs, it would be really close: with the answer to the original question being $- F(a)^2$ compared to $- 2F(a)^2$ in the way I am doing it.

I did the drawings of the regions considered and I can clearly see the missing "infinite square" $(X<a, Y<a)$, but my argument is that if $X$ is the minimum, then $Y$ should be integrated over a region where $Y$ would be the maximum (and vice-versa), hence the difference in the proposed sets considered.

Comment: In (1), what about the case $X\leq a, Y\leq a$?

Comment: Since I derive the $X$,$Y$ limits from $Z$,$W$ I would say that if $Z< \leq a$ and $W \leq b$ it is a necessary condition that $a \leq b$ by definition of $max$ and $min$, therefore that case should not occur. 
I think that the problem in my argument is the following:
Taking $min(5,50)$, $max(5,50)$ I can say that $5 \leq 100$ and that does not imply that $50 \geq 100$.
In general: saying that the $min$ of two numbers is less than another number, doesn't mean that the $max$ of the two is greater than that number. And that is the flaw of my previous reasoning.

Comment: I don't understand, if $X\leq a$ and $Y\leq a$, then automatically, $\min(X,Y)\leq a$ and $\max(X,Y)\leq a\leq b$. But, this case is not covered.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I was trying to say in my comment. You put it more clearly in mathematical terms, but you're right. That was the flaw of my argument, since I was saying that $min(X,Y)\leq a$ implies $a \leq max(X,Y)$, which now I see it is not necessary the case.

Answer (score 0):

Your

$$P( \{X\leq a, a \leq Y\leq b\}  \cup \{a \leq X \leq b, Y\leq a\}  )$$

Is excluding the cases $X<Y<a$ and $X<Y<a$, when *both* $X$ and $Y$ are smaller than $a$.

This is because your expression with either $a \leq Y\leq b$ or $a \leq X\leq b$ you make the restriction that at least one of the variables must be above $a$.

When you incorporate these cases with both $X\leq a, Y \leq a$, then your end result will be increased by $P(X \leq a,Y \leq a) = F(a)^2$. You will get a result of $2F(a)F(b)-F(a)^2$ instead of $2F(a)F(b)-2F(a)^2$